# Como corrigir os problemas relatados com o plugin BlackBox Debug no Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, recuperação-de-erros

Estou enfrentado diversos problemas de velocidade no meu site Wordpress.
Buscando identificar as causas, adicionei o plugin [BlackBox Debug](http://wordpress.org/plugins/blackbox-debug-bar/) que identificou 33,1 erros com o tema que uso, que é bem carregado.

Removi o tema e coloquei um tema básico para ver se persistia e o seguinte log abaixo foi reportado, com ainda 12 erros:

```
Strict (259)    is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 392 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/post.php
Strict (11) is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 498 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php
Strict (3)  is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 75 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php
Strict (2)  is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 105 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php
Strict (6)  is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 160 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php
Strict (12) is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 197 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php
Strict  is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 37 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php
Strict  is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 115 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php
Strict  is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 812 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php
Strict  is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 729 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php
Strict (101)    is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator on line 205 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php
Notice (3)  Trying to get property of non-object on line 597 in file /home/meusite/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php
```

O que significam estes erros? Como posso corrigí-los?

Comment: Qual versão do PHP está instalada no servidor?

Comment: Esta pergunta não é ampla ou pouco clara. Eu, que uso o Wordpress constantemente, entendo perfeitamente qual é o problema. Além do mais, a questão já foi devidamente respondida pelo @Math.

Comment: Concordo que a pergunta foi feito meio largadona a princípio, mas achei precipitada a decisão de fechá-la, ninguém que fechou sequer adicionou um comentário pedindo para o autor elaborar melhor a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_a()` foi aposentado no php 5.0 mas foi reintroduzido no 5.3.

Para solucionar seu problema faça uma atualização do seu PHP.

Referência: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php)

Comment: Correto! Referência da documentação [aqui](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php).

Comment: Boa! faltou uma referência.. Posso adicionar sua sugestão a minha respota?

Comment: Claro, fique à vontade!

Comment: Muito obrigado,foi muito simples e ,apenas uma atualização e ficou limpo!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que é possível verificar neste relatório de erros, é solicitada a substituição do método **is_a()** por **instanceof**, visto que o primeiro é obsoleto (conforme manual do PHP 5).
Por exemplo:

**Onde constar**

```
if (is_a($WF, 'WidgetFactory'))
```

**Sugiro colocar**

```
if ($WF instanceof WidgetFactory)
```

Provavelmente com esta alteração a quantidade de erros encontrados irá diminuir para 1.

Comment: A função `is_a()` não está mais depreciada. Não se deve alterar o *core* do Wordpress por causa disso.

Comment: E.thomas usei a resposta do math por ser mais fácil,mas obrigado mesmo assim,por ter pessoas que ajudam a comunidade desenvolvedora no Brasil,um Abraço.

Comment: Sem problemas @user5004. Fico feliz por também ter aprendido a ler a documentação completa, pois não reparei que a função is_a() foi reativada, cfe: 5.3.0  This function is no longer deprecated, and will therefore no longer throw E_STRICT warnings. (Fonte [http://br1.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php])