# Qual a diferença de var $var e public $var?

Tags: php, classes

Eu tenho uma class:

```
class anyClass{
   public $var1;
   var $var2;
}
```

Qual a diferença de $var1 e $var2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`public $var1` é um membro público da classe os modificadores de acesso foram adicionados no php5.

Já `var $var2` é uma forma de declarar um atributo de uma classe legada do php4 e não deve ser usado em projetos novos, ainda funciona no php5 porém sua visibilidade é a pública.

[Manual - visibilidade](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Ah ta.. ta na documentação.. De hoje que estou procurando.. Passei o olho bem rápido e não achei em Visibilidade falando sobre var. Vou dar mais algumas pesquisadas.

Comment: Interessante é que a documentação avisa que, a partir da versão 5.1.3, usar `var` causaria a invocação de um `E_STRICT`. Porém, em todos os testes que realizei, isso não aconteceu. @_@ ???

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, isso acontece nas versões 5.x até o 5.1.3, depois isso não gerado nenhum warning, é algo parecido com o `E_ALL` e o `E_STRICT`(inserido no php5.3), tem uma outra função que não lembro que so gera warning no php5.1 ... vc pode testar diferentes versões [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) so que o php5.0.4 está offline.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, aqui a [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5173/91) sobre a função que tinha falado, [is_a](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php).

Comment: Descobri que não é possível usar var static. Causaria um `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)..`

Comment: É porque, no caso de uma variável `static`, você pode "omitir" a visibilitade. Exemplo `static $x = 1`, sem o `var`

Answer (score 0):

A variável declarada como `var $var2;` está sendo descontinuada, desde a versão do php4. A partir do php5, foi possível modificar o acesso dos atributos e métodos da classe para possibilitar um alcance mais performático dos objetos, através de heranças, restrições de acessos, polimorfismo, entre outras boas práticas no uso da linguagem PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Era uma forma de se declarar uma um atributo com público. Está em desuso desde o PHP versão 5.

Exemplo de declaração de atributo público utilizando PHP versão 4 ou inferior (prefixo `var`).

```
<?php
    classe Caneta {
        var $modelo;
        var $cor; 
    }
```

Atualmente, para declarar um atributo como público, deve utilizar o prefixo `public` ao invés do `var`, veja como seria o mesmo exemplo com PHP 5 ou superior:

```
<?php
    classe Caneta {
        public $modelo;
        public $cor; 
    }
```